# How to Redirect parent page after some seconds

Tags: php

I am making a page in which there is a submit button. When I click it, it redirects to `karloshopping.php` and opens in a new tab.

How to redirect to the parent page after some seconds to some other page?

```
    <form class="lele" id="lele" name="lele" method="post" action='karloshopping.php?param=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>' target=_blank>
        <input type="submit" value="I Understand,Visit the Retailer" id="lelebtn" class="buttom" name="lelebtn" /><br/>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['lelebtn'])){

}
?>
```

Comment: With JavaScript. The <form target="_blank"> is already busy in your new window, you'll have to add an additional "on submit" event to handle the current window redirection.

Comment: we are on page x suppose clicking submit opens page y ,submit is a form button so url of page is in action,and opens in other tab.Now how to redirect parent page x after few seconds?

Comment: Note that, even though your problem can be helped, you posted an incomplete portion of HTML. Make sure that is orderly in your code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, try redirecting to an empty page at first, something like `action = "empty.php"` and then on that empty page give the header like

```
<?php
header("refresh:5; url=parentpage.php");
echo"you will now be redirected to parentpage.php in 5 seconds..";
?>
```

**EDIT:**

After reading your comment, you could try something like this too;

```
 <form class="lele" id="lele" name="lele" method="post" action='karloshopping.php?param=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>' target=_blank>
        <input type="submit" value="I Understand,Visit the Retailer" id="lelebtn" class="buttom" name="lelebtn" /><br/>
            </form>
        </div><?php
        if(isset($_POST['lelebtn'])){



        }
        ?>
```

In your `karloshopping.php` do something like I did above:

```
<?php
    header("refresh:5; url=parentpage.php");
    echo"you will now be redirected to parentpage.php in 5 seconds..";
    ?>
```

You could also use a JavaScript fucntion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function reDirectit()
    {
    var url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
    window.location(url);
    }
    </script>
```

After our discussion, I think this is exactly what you are looking for;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect()
{
window.location.href="pagez.php";

}
</script>
<form method = "post" action = "pagey.php" target = "_blank">
<input type="submit" value="Go" onClick = "return redirect();" />
</form>
```

Comment: THANKS MATE your code worked but how to make it work when button gets clicked thats the problem

Comment: @ABHI_SINGH You simply click the button and redirects you first page (let's say x.php) and after that header is applied in x.php it will bring you back to parentpage.php. What doesn't work? If you want to have a button that you click and it brings you back then all you have to do is make a button and give the action to the desired page or use headers if they are appropriate in your case :)

Comment: OK bro you re right but i wanted to do it other way round,Thanks

Comment: @ABHI_SINGH which way do you want to do?

Comment: we are on page x submit button clicked page y gets opened in new tab and page x redirects to page z,The way you are telllling is x opens y and y again opens x

Comment: Haha, Thankyou bro. Have a splendid weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = "pagez.php";
}, 8000);
```

8000 means 8 seconds. You can set as per your requirements.